# SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module when trying to import office-ui-fabric in a Gatsbyjs blog

Tags: babeljs, gatsby, office-ui-fabric

I'm trying to add OfficeUI fabric components in a blog build using gatsby js.

As soon as I'm importing any component, the site stop to works.

Using develop command, I can see in the browser console : `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

How to fix this ? (I'm very new to node dev).

Searches I've done suggest problems with babel not using the es2015 preset. However, I double checked, the .babelrc file is mentioning this preset.

Here's the complete operations I've done (on Windows 10 x64 if it matters):

1. cloned the gatsby-starter-blog-no-styles repo :

   ```
   gatsby.cmd new someblog https://github.com/noahg/gatsby-starter-blog-no-styles
   cd someblog
   npm install
   ```

   drink a coffee (will move to yarn soon)
2. Check that works

   ```
   gatsby develop
   ```

   Opened the browser (http://localhost:8000). Its Ok
3. added office ui fabric react components

   ```
   npm install --save office-ui-fabric-react
   ```

   Restart gatsby develop. Still working
4. change src/layouts/index.js file to import an office component

   ```
   import React from 'react'
   import Link from 'gatsby-link'
   import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button'

   class Template extends React.Component {
     ....
   ```

   And voilà! it stop to works. In the browser console, I see an error : `SyntaxError: export declarations may only appear at top level of a module`

I put in GH a complete reproduction repository : https://github.com/stevebeauge/repro-gatsbyjs-officeui-error

[Edit] Digging a bit I can see in the generated 'common.js' file the error :

```
/***/ "./node_modules/office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button.js":
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

    export * from './components/Button/index';
    //# sourceMappingURL=Button.js.map

/***/ }),
```

The export here seems to be forbidden, which leads to Babel issue (not found how to solve though)

Comment: I found that export error can be resolved by changing in you WebPack. Config. Js file in this link https://storybook.js.org/configurations/custom-webpack-config/#full-control-mode--default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recently i stumbled upon the similar error, my solution was to *explicitly* import from `lib-commonjs`:

```
import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib-commonjs/Button';
```

instead of

```
import { Button } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button'
```

Seems to be the error occurs since babel isn't converting `office-ui-fabric-react` to CommonJS module.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling for weeks trying to put everything together. Your solution works like a charm. Though, I'd be interested in getting a solution within the gatsby build